# VBA Shell command - how to format

Tags: vba, shell, unc

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to format a VBA shell command to launch MS Access and preload a network based database. I have tried this with the normal windows path and using a UNC i.e Shell "msaccess.exe \\OMRSRV\Projects\Clients\HP\DailyCustomerSatisfaction\HP.accde", vbMaximizedFocus

Cant get it to work - Invalid procedure call or argument!

Comment: This `Shell "msaccess.exe c:\temp\temp_db.accdb", vbMaximizedFocus` works fine when running in VBA in Excel. Which part of Office are you using to run the VBA?

Comment: You can also try wrapping the path to the database file in quotes: `Shell "msaccess.exe " & Chr$(34) & "c:\some path\temp db.accdb" & Chr$(34), vbMaximizedFocus` in case there are any spaces, etc in the path.

Comment: @ChipsLetten Yes indeed that works fine, however it doesnt work when the database is on a network resource! Tried with both mapped drives and the UNC format including the server name. Its being run via user button_click in Outlook.

Comment: @ChipsLetten Your Chr$(34) suggestion is not having it either unfortunately same error - Invalid procedure call!

Comment: I can understand that UNC might not work but a mapped drive should be fine. Can only offer couple more ideas - 1) presumably simply starting Access from the shell command works fine? 2) Can you create a desktop shortcut that works ok? Looking at the properties of the shortcut might give you inspiration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ChipsLetten you kicked the cage nicely there even if you didnt directly offer the solution: it could not have been simpler - msaccess.exe required its path to be included in the statement!